# Can't find the heatmap on Grad-CAM in my model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have trained a model for image classification into 3 classes and I have used the guide on keras website for [Grad-CAM](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/#setup). as follows:
**Load Model**

```
RN50V2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/Grad_CAM_Test/ResNet50V2_/RN50V2.h5')
```

and I use `RN50V2.summary()` which found that, `last_conv_layer_name = 'conv5_block3_3_conv'`.
After that, I use model `RN50V2` for prediction on the test set.

```
batch_size = 32
test_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    '/content/drive/MyDrive/Test_150',
    image_size = (224, 224),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    shuffle = False
)
```

**Iterate over the test dataset batches**

```
images_batch = [] # list of images in test_dataset
labels_batch = [] # list of labels in test_dataset
for dataset in test_dataset.unbatch():
  image_batchh, label_batchh = dataset
  images = image_batchh.numpy() # Convert Tensor of image_batch to numpy
  labels = label_batchh.numpy() # Convert Tensor of label_batch to numpy
  images_batch.append(images)
  labels_batch.append(labels)
```

Next, I want to test the images in GRAD-CAM. So, I create a array of image in test dataset.
In this case, **images_batch[0] is the first image in test_dataset.**

```
array_of_img = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(images_batch[0]) #Convert Tensor to array
array_of_img = np.expand_dims(array_of_img, axis=0) #(1,224,224,3)
print(array_of_img)
```

After that, I create the Grad-CAM Algorithm by use the guide code from [Grad-CAM](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/#setup).
**Grad-CAM Algorithm**

```
def make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, pred_index=None):
    # First, we create a model that maps the input image to the activations
    # of the last conv layer as well as the output predictions
    grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        [RN50V2.inputs], [RN50V2.get_layer('conv5_block3_3_conv').output, RN50V2.output]
    )

    # Then, we compute the gradient of the top predicted class for our input image
    # with respect to the activations of the last conv layer
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img_array)
        if pred_index is None:
            pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
        class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]

    # This is the gradient of the output neuron (top predicted or chosen)
    # with regard to the output feature map of the last conv layer
    grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)

    # This is a vector where each entry is the mean intensity of the gradient
    # over a specific feature map channel
    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))

    # We multiply each channel in the feature map array
    # by "how important this channel is" with regard to the top predicted class
    # then sum all the channels to obtain the heatmap class activation
    last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output[0]
    heatmap = last_conv_layer_output @ pooled_grads[..., tf.newaxis]
    heatmap = tf.squeeze(heatmap)

    # For visualization purpose, we will also normalize the heatmap between 0 & 1
    heatmap = tf.maximum(heatmap, 0) / tf.math.reduce_max(heatmap)
    return heatmap.numpy()
```

**Test Grad-CAM**

```
# Prepare image
img_array = array_of_img

# Make model
model = RN50V2

# Remove last layer's softmax
model.layers[-1].activation = None

# Print what the top predicted class is
preds = model.predict(img_array)

# Generate class activation heatmap
heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, RN50V2, 'conv5_block3_3_conv')

# Display heatmap
plt.matshow(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

[image: Grad-CAM]

The output from Test Grad-CAM, I don't see the heatmap on last convolution layer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try producing the heatmap for other images from the test dataset? You can also examine the `pooled_grads` array.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal, I found the problem that `convolution layer in model`. I tried to change the convolution layer in model. I'm not sure it will be about the base model. In this case, I use ResNet50v2 is the base model.